# Exceeded max configured index size while indexing document while running LS Agent

Tags: indexing, lotus-notes, lotusscript

In our project we have a LS agent which is supposed to delete and create a new FT index. We haven't figured out yet why updating the index cannot be accomplished automatically(although in our database option this is set to update the index daily). So we decided to make roughly the same thing, but using our very simple agent. The agent looks like this and runs daily in the night:

```
Option Public

Option Declare

Dim s As NotesSession
Dim ndb As NotesDatabase

Sub Initialize

    Set s = New NotesSession
    Set ndb = s.CurrentDatabase
    Print("BEFORE REMOVING INDEXES")
    Call ndb.Removeftindex()
    Print("INDEXES HAVE BEEN REMOVED SUCCESSFULLY")
    Call ndb.createftindex(FTINDEX_ALL_BREAKS, true)
    Print("INDEXES HAVE BEEN CREATED SUCCESSFULLY")

End Sub
```

In most cases it works very well, but sometimes when somebody creates a document which exceeds 12MB (we really don't know how this is possible) the agent fails to create the index. (but the latest index is already deleted). 
Error message is:

```
31.05.2018 03:01:25   Full Text Error (FTG): Exceeded max configured index 
size while indexing document NT000BD992 in database index *path to FT file*.ft
```

My question is how to avoid this problem? We've already expanded the limit of 6MB by the following command `SET CONFIG FTG_INDEX_LIMIT=12582912`. Can we expand it even more? And in general, how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but... why have such an agent at all? Domino full-text indexes normally update automatically every 15 minutes to include new and modified documents since the last update, and can be configured to update on different schedules without any coding. You shouldn't need an agent like this unless your index often becomes corrupted and, if that is happening, you may have bigger problems and should probably rethink your application design.

Answer (score 0):

Using FTG_INDEX_LIMIT is an option to avoid this error, yes. But it will impact server performance in two ways - FTI-update processes will take more time and more memory.
There's no max size of this limit (in theory), but! As update-processes eats memory from common heap it can lead to 'out-of-memory-overheaping' and server crash.
You can try to exclude attachments from index - i don't think someone can put more than 1mb of text in one doc, but users can attach some big text files - and this will produce the error you writing about.

p.s. and yeah, i agree with Scott - why do you need such agent anyway? common ft-indexing working fine usualy.